# Generalize matrix multiplication with numpy

Tags: python, numpy

I have the following code snippet:

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3)
b = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
c = np.zeros((2,3))
c[0] = a[0] @ b[0]
c[1] = a[1] @ b[1]
```

How do I generalize that for any `a(n,3,3)`, `b(n,3)` and `c(n,3)`?

I think `einsum` is the way to go but I can't quite figure the right syntax...

Comment: `a @ b[:,:,None]` should produce a (2,3,1), which you can then squeeze to (2,3).  You want to treat the first dimension of each as the 'batch' one, which for `@` must be the first of 3.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you could broadcast or use einsum (better einsum):

```
import numpy as np
a = np.arange(18).reshape(2,3,3)
b = np.arange(6).reshape(2,3)
c = np.zeros((2,3))
c[0] = a[0] @ b[0]
c[1] = a[1] @ b[1]

res_broad = (a*b[:,None,:]).sum(2)

res_ein = np.einsum('ijk,ik->ij',a,b)

print(f"broadcast works: {np.allclose(c,res_broad)}")
print(f"einsum works: {np.allclose(c,res_broad)}")
```